# HTML5 import function doesn't work in all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, html-imports

I'd a requirement of importing a common HTML file in other files so that it can be re-used.
I followed [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) article and the concept works absolutely fine in Chrome. But it doesn't seem to work in Firefox and IE. Later I found out that only Chrome( V.36.0 onwards) supports it as of now.

I want to ask is there a workaround to make the functionality work across browsers?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a polyfill. There's one in the webcomponents package: [polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs).

Comment: why is this answer not chosen as it answers to the question?

Comment: @Supersharp I don't know why, but if you like it you can upvote ;-)

Comment: i've already upvoted (it was me...). I'm fed up with people that ask tons of questions and never retribute the ones who spent some time trying to help.

Comment: @Supersharp 1. thanks 2. yeah, that's quite annoying, but not much we can do, right?